# Navigation component doesn't pop fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

When we open the application, I show an intro fragment. In the intro fragment after some time, I navigate the user to the feed fragment. On the feed fragment when the user presses the back button, I need to show an exit dialog. When the user will click exit, I need to close the app.

This is my navigation graph.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
app:startDestination="@+id/fragment_intro">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_feed"
    android:name="FeedFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_feed"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_intro"
    android:name="IntroFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_intro">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_introFragment_to_feedFragment"
        app:destination="@id/fragment_feed"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mobile_navigation"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

</fragment>
</navigation>
```

So here is it. My start destination is the Intro fragment. And I have an action, which navigates me to the feed fragment. And I pop my intro fragment, when I navigate to the feed fragment.

Regarding to the code, in the intro fragment, I navigate to the feed fragment after 3 seconds.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val action = IntroFragmentDirections.actionIntroFragmentToFeedFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }, 3000)
}
```

So in the feed fragment, when the user clicks the back button, I need to show an exit dialog. That means, I need to catch the back press, which I've done in this way.
In the onCreateView() of my feed fragment I've added this

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
        viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Show exit dialog
            }
        }
    )
```

And when the user clicks on the back button, simply I call this function

```
fun onExit() {
    findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

But when I click on the exit button, it returns back to the intro fragment, which I've popped. So why it isn't popping, what am I doing wrong?

**---EDIT---**

One solution is to remove the `dispatcherCallback` and call `onBackPressed()`, but I don't think that's a good one.

```
val onBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Show exit dialog
        }
    }
    
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
    viewLifecycleOwner, onBackPressedCallback 
)
    
fun onExit() {
    onBackPressedCallback.remove()
    activity?.onBackPressed()
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: use requireActivity().finish()  instead of onBackPressed . maybe it  helped

Comment: But it's a fragment. Finish will just close my activity, right?

Comment: I thought when we set our fragement in mainactivity with jetpack component or anything else when we close that all the fragment will automatically  be closed.

Comment: You're right. But if there will be a case, when I don't need all the fragments to be closed, I need to write if statement for that. But if you look at the code below EDIT, for that I don't need any if statement. It will close only this fragment and if there will be empty in the backstack, my app will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I've found the solution, maybe this will help someone. So the issue that the fragment didn't pop is, because when we have only one fragment in our `backstack`, or we try to pop our start destination fragment, `navigateUp()` function will return false and the fragment will not be popped. So why is that happening? Because `navigateUp` navigates to the previous fragment in your navigation host. But if there is no fragment, where our navigation controller could navigate, it simply returns false. So we need a function to determine whether this is the only fragment in our graph, and we can't navigate up or we can. Because calling every time `activity?.onBackPressed()` is not a good solution. So to achieve this, we can create an extension function like this:

```
fun NavController.navigateUpOrFinish(activity: FragmentActivity): Boolean {
    return if (navigateUp()) {
        true
    } else {
        activity.finish()
        true
    }
}
```

That's all. Now we can call this function on the dialog exit click

```
fun onExit() {
    findNavController().navigateUpOrFinish(requireActivity())
}
```

And if there will be a fragment, where we can navigate, it will call `navigateUp()` in other cases, it will simply call backPressed and our app will be closed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me from going mad, I didn't notice that I was popping all the way to the root fragment/navgraph and navigating to another nav host, that's why it was popping all the back stack but not the start destination